# dynamic navigation in php

Tags: php, dynamic, navigation

How do i implement a dynamic navigation in php?

e.g

Home | about  | contact  | faq | tutorials

i need to automatically generate the links dynamically respectively to each page without much script. e.g i should have all the links without manually entering the links to each other page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to display a menu for a known set of pages without re-architecting your current code, how about this:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'index.php' => 'Home',
    'about.php' => 'About',
    'contact.php' => 'Contact',
    'faq.php' => 'FAQ',
    'tutorials.php' => 'Tutorials',
) ;

$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;

?>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuList">
        <?php foreach ($pages as $filename => $pageTitle) { 
            if ($filename == $currentPage) { ?>
        <li class="current"><?php echo $pageTitle ; ?></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $filename ; ?>"><?php echo $pageTitle ; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            } //if 
         } //foreach 
            ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Put this in its own file, say `menu.php`, and then include it in each page. Then you can [style your menu](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) with CSS.

Comment: i have already done this in my own style, but for each sub directory i go deep down, i still have to loop and test each page, and this navigation depends on the host. i usually have problems in xampp. you have to create a virtual sub domain for this to work

Comment: @Oghenero you have multiple files in multiple subdirectories that you don't have a definite list for and you need the script to dynamically explore the filesystem and find them?

Comment: @Fanis *"You may want to look into the Linked question that @ Sebastian P provided"* - I found this Q&A from someone who posted a possible duplicate in another question. That linked page in comments has been deleted by a (then) moderator. Just thought you'd like to know that and if you wish to update your answer in regards to that.

Comment: @Fanis You can scratch comment above, since I made the edit. The link in comments was removed.

Answer (score 2):

i agree with the first solution even if its a bit simply. For me you have to split your website into some script where you include your navigation script like the second solution.

but if you really want to make a dynamic navigation, your data cant be write in a file and they are stock in a database or on an xml file....
to do that you have to create a class or a function who parse your data and create array like first solution.

```
 /* header.php (main header template)*/
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
     <div id="mainMenu">
          <?php echo Navigation::getNav($databaseCnx);?>
     </div>
```

and in another script you have to create a class who manage the data

```
<?php 
class Navigation{
    static function getNav($cnx){
         $menuList = '<ul>';
         $dataFromDataBase = $cnx->getArray('MySqlRequest');

         foreach($dataFromDataBase as $menu) {
              $menuList  .='<li><a href="'.$menu->uri.'">'.$menu->name.'</a></li>';
         }

         $menuList .= '</ul>';

         return $menuList;
    }
}
```

i write it fast but i hope i can help some who look for tips to create dynamic menu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to include a menu file in all your pages.
You can use include().

In all your pages:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php include('navigation.php'); ?>

    Contents of this page here...

  </body>
</html>
```

And in navigation.php:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
  <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="about.php">About</a> | etc...
</div>
```

This way you can update your navigation menu just once for all your pages.