# Dynamic navigation in php with sub-menus without database

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, navigation

Using the method/answer prescribed here: [dynamic navigation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909467/1892007)

I'd like to add to it with but a handfull of page-links as sub-menus.

I've got this in play (from the previous answered question)

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'index.php' => 'Home',
    'about.php' => 'About',
    'contact.php' => 'Contact',
    'faq.php' => 'FAQ',
    'tutorials.php' => 'Tutorials',
) ;

$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;

?>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuList">
        <?php foreach ($pages as $filename => $pageTitle) { 
            if ($filename == $currentPage) { ?>
        <li class="current"><?php echo $pageTitle ; ?></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $filename ; ?>"><?php echo $pageTitle ; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            } //if 
         } //foreach 
            ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to add sub-menu items to the About menu item, or the FAQ menu.

I'm getting lost though in the php portion of hunt-and-peck till something works. :)

Granted, as it is only at most a 10 page site, I could simply have the menu code in each of the pages. But what kind of learning-experiment would that be? 
:)

Thanks in advance for any insights for this "designer-wannabe-coder"

ps. much thanks to [Fanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137259/fanis) for their code above

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you are asking for? Are you just in need of help in understanding the PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SPAGUETTI CODE ALERT]**

You could try this,

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'index.php' => 'Home',
    'about.php' => array('pageTitle' => 'About', 'subpages' => array(
        'about1.php' => 'About subpage #1',
        'about2.php' => 'About subpage #2',
        'about3.php' => 'About subpage #3')),        
    'contact.php' => 'Contact',
    'faq.php' => 'FAQ',
    'tutorials.php' => 'Tutorials',
) ;

$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;

?>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuList">
    <?php foreach ($pages as $filename => $value) {

        if (is_array ($value)) {
            $pageTitle = $value ['pageTitle'];
        } else {
            $pageTitle = $value;
        }

        if ($filename == $currentPage) {
            $attr_current = ' class="current"';
        } else {
            $attr_current = '';
        }
        ?>
        <li<?php echo $attr_current; ?>><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $pageTitle ; ?></a>

        <?php if (is_array ($value)) { ?>
            <ul id="submenuList">
            <?php foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) { ?> 
                <li><a href="<?php echo $subfilename; ?>"><?php echo $subpageTitle ; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } ?>

        </li>

    <?php } //foreach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see it is not the cleanest solution ever so if I were to do something like this I would write the code above like this:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'index.php' => 'Home',
    'about.php' => array('pageTitle' => 'About', 'subpages' => array(
        'about1.php' => 'About subpage #1',
        'about2.php' => 'About subpage #2',
        'about3.php' => 'About subpage #3')),        
    'contact.php' => 'Contact',
    'faq.php' => 'FAQ',
    'tutorials.php' => 'Tutorials',
) ;

$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;

?>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuList">
    <?php foreach ($pages as $filename => $value):

        $pageTitle = is_array ($value) ? $value ['pageTitle'] : $value;   
        $attr_current = $filename == $currentPage ? ' class="current"' : '';
        ?>
        <li<?=$attr_current?>><a href="<?=$filename?>"><?=$pageTitle?></a>

        <?php if (is_array ($value)): ?>
            <ul id="submenuList">
            <?php foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle): ?> 
                <li><a href="<?=$subfilename?>"><?=$subpageTitle?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not really neat either but..

If you want to use the latter just keep in mind:

- It uses the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
- It uses the short tag `<?=` about which you should read [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694) to see whether you can or cannot use it
- Read about the CSS you must use for the `submenuList` [here](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest... Simply add another dimension to the array. :)

Comment: Sweet. I'll give this a go. ( and maybe start searching for a nice php primer as well. {humbled-grin} )

Comment: Great. If this works for you please consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: Sweet. This seems to be working as expected Digitalis. Thanks!

I might add though that your first self-proclaimed 'dirty' solution worked, and the one sent through the washer simply spit out bullets, left, and right brackets. ;)

Comment: Answer Accepted Digitalis! :)